# System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection and System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions both have same simple name of 'IgnoreRouteInternal'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-routing, notsupportedexception

I’ve got an ASP.NET MVC project which I haven't worked on in almost two months. Debugging in a browser works fine as long as I don’t change ANY code. The moment I modify any code whatsoever, even adding whitespace, I get this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection+IgnoreRouteInternal' and the type 'System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions+IgnoreRouteInternal' both have the same simple name of 'IgnoreRouteInternal' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.
```

The exception happens on this line:

```
var item = Cards.FirstOrDefault(s => s.name == cardName);
```

The only things I can think of is that changing the Routing settings was probably one of the last things I did before I picked this project up again, as far as I can tell everything is normal there. The other thing is that I’m using TortiseGit and bitbucket but I don’t see what effect that would have. I’ve got another project with a similar setup that has no issues.

In case I have made a mistake this is my RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace houseOfCards
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Hello",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}"
                );
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to resolve this, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue, after three days of investigating and debugging I managed to fix it, the error message tends to be a bit misleading, because it only refers to the `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection` and the `System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions` classes, and that leads one to think routes have something to do with it, but they don't, at least in my case.

In my case I mistakenly declared an entity's navigation property as `ICollection<Controller>`, so Entity Framework was getting all confused about the classes I wanted to register.

So, I'd recommend searching your model for any property or class named as a reserved word or a class that doesn't belong to the model and rename it.

I hope it helps

Comment: Perfect suggestion! For what ever reason there were some generated public methods from the controller that were causing the issue. Deleting them solved the problem. Thanks!