# I can't figure out what's going on with my entity framework MVC setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

SpectrumContext is the connection defined in web.config. I'm not sure why this is not loading.

My string variable "results" is throwing following error:

> The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection+IgnoreRouteInternal' and
>   the type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions+IgnoreRouteInternal' both
>   have the same simple name of 'IgnoreRouteInternal' and so cannot be
>   used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique
>   simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code
>   First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the
>   model.

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Controllers;
using WebApplication1.DataAccessLayer;
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BaseContext db1 = new BaseContext("SpectrumContext");
        string sql = "select description from dbo.workcategory where workcategoryid = 3";

        string results = db1.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sql).First();

        return View(results);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

BaseContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
`test`using WebApplication1.Controllers;

namespace WebApplication1.DataAccessLayer
{
public class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected string connectionName;
    public DbSet<HomeController> description { get; set; }

    /**
     * Created the connection to the server using the giving connection string name
     * 
     * @param connName
     */
    public BaseContext(string connName = "SpectrumContext")
        : base(connName)
    {
        connectionName = connName;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the default database
     * 
     * @param databaseName
     */
    public BaseContext setDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

        //change the database before creating the new connection
        builder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;

        string sqlConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

        return new BaseContext(sqlConnectionString);
    }
}
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>ASP.NET</h1>

</div>

<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Anything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553883/system-web-routing-routecollection-and-system-web-mvc-routecollectionextensions) help you?

Comment: Where is it throwing that Exception?

Comment: Why are you trying to persist HomeController instances in your database?  That's unusual.

Comment: @mxmissile at  string results = db1.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sql).First(); is where it is throwing exception.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I really don't know what I'm doing. All I want to do is run straight SQL statements and have them return to the view within MVC when I need to. And the examples and tutorials out there are horrible/incomplete and trying to piece them together and follow along has me very frustrated.

Comment: If you are just going to run queries like that you might as well use ADO.NET since you are not gaining the benefit of EF. There's a ton of good starter material on the topic. For example [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/).

Comment: Remove `public DbSet<HomeController> description { get; set; }'  That line of code declares that you want to store HomeController instances in your database, which you don't.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Now I'm getting a different error....The view 'Molding' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Molding.aspx
~/Views/Home/Molding.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Molding.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Molding.ascx
~/Views/Home/Molding.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Molding.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Molding.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Molding.vbhtml

Comment: It sounds like the result of the query you ran is the word "Molding."  What you're returning is an ActionResult what you're returning is the action "Molding." The error is telling you have have no actions by that name, which is true.  I think you need to step back and re-read about MVC.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, if all your wanting to do is execute simple SQL statements, ditch the (EF) `DbContext` for now until you understand how EF works and what it's used for.

While you are learning, you can execute simple SQL statements using raw ADO like this:

```
const string sql = "select description from dbo.workcategory where workcategoryid = 3";
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SpectrumContext"].ConnectionString;
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        var results = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        return View(results);
     }
}
```